# C++ IDE для Win под OpenMP/CL/CV

Tags: c++, ide, opencv, openmp, opencl

Какую простую бесплатную IDE с автодополнениями и прочими стандартными вещами можете посоветовать для кроссплатформенного С++ (11) кода на Win7. Visual Studio Comm понаставил кучу ненужных допов, SQL сервер и прочей ненужной дряни,Visual Studio Express насколько я помню вообще с внешними библиотеками плохо дружит, думал про Dev-C++ но у него плохо с поддержкой OpenMP/CL/CV, основная задача это учится писать кроссплатформенный код под OpenMP/CL/CV, ясно что если нужно GUI под Win то это Visual Studio, а кроссплатформенный это Qt. Думал про Qt но там всё сложно с лицензиями и куча версий , да и избыточнен он для такой задачи,

Comment: а в чём, по-вашему, состоит «сложность с лицензиями» у *qt*?

Comment: там много версий и я только поверхностно читал что там к чему, потому что , ну для такого QT излишен всётаки, хотя может там и есть какая-то версия чисто С++ без редактора GUI

Comment: vnn198, как минимум три (gplv3, lgplv3, lgplv2.1) из четырёх лицензий, под которыми распространяется *qt*, не накладывают никаких ограничений на создаваемые с помощью *qt* программы. если есть вопросы по этому поводу — задавайте их здесь: вроде бы, в результате обсуждения на мете, сошлись на том, что вопросы лицензирования п.о. укладываются в тематику сайта.

Comment: Почему Visual Studio? У меня под виндозой проект, использующий OpenCV прекрасно собирается под QtCreator + MinGW32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code::Blocks. Простая, бесплатная, автодополнение OpenMP работает "из коробки", для OpenCV тоже. Поддерживает множество компиляторов, удобный и функциональный интерфейс, можно быстро сделать GUI в встроенном плагине wxSmith (библиотека wxWidgets).

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.

Comment: @metalurgus а в чем проблема? На вопрос я ответил, так как попросили посоветовать IDE. Ссылка так, чтобы побыстрее перейти на сайт IDE.

Comment: В том, что ответы-ссылки запрещены.

Comment: @metalurgus ссылка НЕ ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ ответом. Был вопрос: "Какую простую бесплатную IDE с автодополнениями и прочими стандартными вещами можете посоветовать для кроссплатформенного С++ (11) кода на Win7". Ответом является фраза "Я бы порекомендовал Code::Blocks". Ссылка просто так, чтобы можно было сразу перейти и посмотреть, подходит или нет данная IDE. Или по вашему ссылки вообще нельзя вставить в ответ?

Comment: ну уж "Я бы порекомендовал" тем более не является ответом. Ссылки можно вставлять, если они являются источником вашего ответа, а не его содержимым. В любом случае, такие вопросы запрещены, т. к. на них нельзя дать однозначный ответ.

Comment: ссылки в любом случае полезны, запрещать их это маразм, не 19 век всётаки, а если по теме, что такое C::B Share Config ?? . по Contrib плагинам я описание нашёл

Comment: @vnn198 утилита для сохранения и переноса конфигурации между разными установками C::B. [Тут](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=3807.0) разработчиком несколько подробнее написано о функционале.

Comment: Понятно, я то думал это какая-то утилита для переноска кода из С/С++ в В

Comment: Вот только не обновлялась эта IDE уже полтора года